# How to return a list of results in jOOQ Mocked Data

Tags: java, jdbc, jooq

I'm using jOOQ's MockDataProvider to mock calls to the database.  I've figured out how to return a single record using the information here: https://blog.jooq.org/2013/02/20/easy-mocking-of-your-database/

However, I want to return a list of results not just a single record for my query.  How do I do that?

I can use the following (from the above link) to return a single result:

```
return new MockResult[] {
  new MockResult(1, result)
};
```

However, I cannot figure out how to add multiple results, all of the constructors for MockResult only take a single result.  Any hints?  Am I missing something obvious?

For example if I query all bicycles that are road bikes:
`SELECT * FROM bicycles WHERE type = "road";`
how do I return a list of 10 bicycles instead of just one?

Comment: What do you mean by multiple results? Multiple result sets, as e.g. when calling SQL server batches or stored procedures that yield more than one result set? Could you perhaps show an example of what you're trying to mock, and what your client code looks like (which uses the mock)?

Comment: I added an example above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can use the following (from the above link) to return a single result

But that's already it. You return a single result with several records. The result you pass to that `MockResult` constructor could look like this:

```
var result = ctx.newResult(BICYCLES.COL1, BICYCLES.COL2);
result.add(ctx.newRecord(BICYCLES.COL1, BICYCLES.COL2).values(1, 2));
result.add(ctx.newRecord(BICYCLES.COL1, BICYCLES.COL2).values(3, 4));
...
```